# how to notify NSFetchRequestController if an attribute of an object in relationship chain is changed

Tags: ios, objective-c, core-data

[image]

Consider the above model, I have an FRC (NSFetchRequestController) on Items. I want FRC to update view, if Person is changed.

I know I can observe NSManagedObjectContextObjectsDidChangeNotification for changes, but this doesnt look intuitive.

I was thinking calling willChangeValueForKey and didChangeValueForKey will do the trick but it didnt worked as expected.

```
            Person *person = [NSEntityDescription
                                  insertNewObjectForEntityForName:@"Person"
                                  inManagedObjectContext:temporaryContext];

            person.name= [msg objectForKey:@"name"];


//            [?? willChangeValueForKey:@"friendPhoneNumber"];
//            [?? didChangeValueForKey:@"friendPhoneNumber"];

            // Save the context.
            NSError *error = nil;

            if (![temporaryContext save:&error]) {
                NSLog(@"Error in Saving MOC: %@",[error description]);
            }

            [managedObjectContext performBlock:^{
                // Save the context.
                NSError *error = nil;
                if (![managedObjectContext save:&error]) {
                    DLog(@"Error in Saving MOC: %@",[error description]);
                }

                [writerObjectContext performBlock:^{
                    // Save the context.
                    NSError *error = nil;
                    if (![writerObjectContext save:&error]) {
                        DLog(@"Error in Saving MOC: %@",[error description]);
                    }else{
                        [writerObjectContext refreshObject:changedObjectId mergeChanges:YES];
                    }

                }]; // writer
            }]; // main
        }]; // parent
```

Comment: Explain more details, which property of Person should be observed?
If possible, provide code snippets

Comment: Grrr !! I wish i could provide code. 

for instace name should be observed.

Comment: Added code for explanation

Comment: Please explain what "it didnt worked as expected" means.

Comment: I wanted to notify FRC on items that person has been modified, but it didnt worked as expected. FRC doesnt register any change

Comment: Please post the code you used to create your FRC.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I wanted to notify FRC on items that person has been modified, but it
>   didnt worked as expected. FRC doesnt register any change.

A `NSFetchedController`registers changes only for the entity is associated with. As you described, that is the `Item` entity. If a `Person` changes, the fetched controller will not respond to changes.

If you want to repond to changes, you need to do it manually. An example explanation can be found at [NSFetchedResultsController pitfall](http://www.mlsite.net/blog/?p=825).

A simple question, why the items should change on person modifications? Maybe you should perform a new request...only suppositions.

Comment: Actually my problem is exactly the same, and I've been thinking on these lines too.

I think it didnt worked because ive been calling willChange/didChange on a set. Let me see and I'll get back to you